# What if there were no kohanim?

Tags: halacha-theory, kohen-priest, genealogy, temple-service-avoda, invalid-pasul

I don't know if this question was asked before, but:

If, hypothetically, when the Mikdash will be built, somehow it was discovered that all kohanim were genealogically invalidated - chalalim in the lineage, converts, etc.<sup>1</sup> What then? Would there be service in the Mikdash? Who would serve?

---

<sup>1</sup> In this hypothetical situation, let's assume that there was a way to be certain of this 100% percent.

Comment: See H. Melakhim 12:3. Our Prophets, as understood by our Sages, assure us that this hypothetical will not materialize. One of the functions of משיח will be to purify/identify lineages.

Comment: @Deuteronomy Thanks. I don't believe this is something that will happen, which is why I merely asking it as a hypothetical, out of curiosity. Probably not much crazier than someone throwing his wife a get from the second story and it bursts into flames on the way down, eh?

Comment: I am suggesting that methodologically the approach would be different. A priori we assume that we will have Kohanim, as per the Neviim (as understood by Hazal). The hypothetical of a get bursting into flames does not involve denying the sixth iqar emunah (or the second shoresh if you're looking through R. Yosef Albo's lens).

Comment: @Deuteronomy is there a difference in principle between having no Kohanim and therefore not being able to do mitzvos involving them vs. having no Amalek and not being able to kill them?

Comment: @Heshy yes, for the same aforementioned reason.

Comment: I remember hearing that once Mashiach arrives the avodah will revert back to the first born (perhaps in addition to kohanim). If so, they would be eligible to do the service even if there’s no kohanim

Comment: Is a kohen defined as Aharon and his descendants?  Or as somebody designated by Hashem as a kohen and his descendants (which so far includes Aharon, his 4 sons, and Pinchas, but Hashem could later add more)?  In general from Tzav, Shemini, end of Yechezkel, etc. is that hilchos kodshim have a lot of seemingly one-time halachos, but maybe those halachos reflect a deeper structure that Hashem might tell a navi to have us use again in the future.

Comment: @Heshy Lo Bashamayim He?

Comment: @Heshy the Kehuna is only entrusted to the descendants of Aaron: ואת אהרן ואת בניו תפקד ושמרו את כהנתם והזר הקרב יומת

Comment: A hypothetical of this type is not really valid. Since we know the bais hamikdash will be rebuilt and we will have korbanos, we know that there would be kohanim

Comment: @sabbahillel very true. But *who* will those kohanim be is the main subject of this question.