# What would happen if the Jewish people became completely composed of non ethnic Jews

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism

Undoubtedly, Judaism- though not proselytizing  our beliefs - does accept Converts and Jews are commanded to love and respect the convert. What would happen if the Jewish people, over time, became completely non ethnic Jewish. Meaning descendants of converts - or converts themselves.

What Halachic implications would that have? Would having no more Kohanim, male descendants of Aharon Hakohen, preclude the coming of Moshiach?

Would building the Beis Hamikdash become moot?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/128716/what-if-there-were-no-kohanim

Comment: See also: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/33475/27180

Comment: See Kiddushin 71a, 76b

Comment: It's not possible. There is a promise that not even one shevet will die out.

Comment: @N.T. Who said that means they die out. Demographics doesn’t mean you die out. America in 1990 was 90% white. Now it’s 60%. Does that mean they die. Or that more white people intermarried with non whites.

Comment: You said completely non ethnic Jewish. So they would have to die out by definition.

Comment: @N.T. Meaning all males are either converts or descendants of converts - but mothers are ethnically Jewish

Comment: @kouty what am I looking for specifically

Comment: @ShoelU'Meishiv but a convert has no shevet (since one cannot reside with a tribe in a particular area outside Israelhttps://www.yeshiva.co/ask/1645 ) and the "shevet" won't die out, then there can't be only converts remaining.

Comment: כיון שנתמעו נתמעו